# How do you relocate NPCs?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I can't find any button to relocate NPCs in Mobile Terraria. Can someone tell me where the button is?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, there is not yet a [Housing Menu](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Inventory#Housing_menu) on the iOS version of Terraria. That would make it much easier to relocate NPCs. However, the classic way to do this from the earlier (pre 1.1) days of Terraria still works!

Assume Merchant lives in house A and you want him to be in house B
[image: The Merchant]

- Make all other housing not currently occupied unsuitable (such as removing the table)
- Make house A unsuitable.
- Wait for the Merchant to move to house B.
- Put back all the tables

There is also a less reliable and more evil method: keep killing the Merchant until he moves into the right house.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to disappoint you, but I don't think there is a way to do this. Terraria on iOS came out recently compared to on the PC. Maybe in the future there will be an update so you can do this.

Answer (score -1):

Say you want to move Merchant from house A to house B. This only works if House B is not already occupied. Destroy house A and Merchant will move into house B. Then remake house A.

Answer (score -3):

Occupy all the houses except the house you want him to move in to and wait for him to move in that house.

Answer (score -4):

Yeah their right.
Sorry either kill him,
Remove the whole room,
Or remove the chairs and tables 
And wait for him to leave